# Do children in daycare have elevated cortisol levels?

Tags: medical-science, education, children

An article named [Children's elevated cortisol levels at daycare](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0885200606000421) is used to argue against daycare.

> Our main finding was that at daycare children display higher cortisol levels compared to the home setting. [...] We speculate that children in center daycare show elevated cortisol levels because of their stressful interactions in a group setting.

Comment: thx @Avery for the edit!

Comment: And are higher (how much?) cortisol levels inherently bad?

Comment: @Jan that is a separate question, or maybe something for [health.se] or [fitness.se].

Comment: "Hell is other people".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two brand-new, publicly accessible review articles confirm that this study had a sampling bias. It's basically children from low-risk, middle-class white backgrounds that exhibit higher cortisol levels in day care. Children from other backgrounds may have positive results, depending on the quality of care.

[Child Care and Cortisol Across Infancy and Toddlerhood: Poverty, Peers, and Developmental Timing](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/fare.12184/full) (2016)

> For children from high-risk contexts, within-child increases in child
>   care hours were predictive of cortisol decreases. The inverse was
>   evident for children from low-risk contexts. This relation grew across
>   toddlerhood. Whereas a history of greater center-based child care was
>   predictive of heightened cortisol levels for low-risk families, this
>   was not the case for children from high-risk families. Irrespective of
>   risk, greater peer exposure (between children) was associated with
>   lower cortisol levels.

[A review of research on the effects of Early Childhood Education and Care (ECEC) upon child development](http://dspace.library.uu.nl/handle/1874/326604) (2015)

> A recent review of the largest and most representative childcare
>   studies in the US and many smaller studies concluded that the effects
>   of quantity of care on children’s behaviour problems were population
>   specific: for disadvantaged children and those from minority ethnic
>   families, extensive childcare was not associated with more
>   externalizing problems – in some cases it predicted lower levels,
>   possibly compensating for other disadvantages (Huston et al., 2015).